# WHM - Monitorar Mysql por site

Tags: mysql, cpanel, whm

Preciso monitorar o uso de Mysql por usário em meu Cpanel.

Como posso monitorar o uso de Mysql separado por cliente Cpanel no meu WHM?

Existe alguma solução para isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um plugin gratuito chamado "WatchMySQL":

https://www.ndchost.com/cpanel-whm/addons/watchmysql/

- Configura limite de conexões por usuário, pacote/package ou globalmente
- Dispara emails de alerta quando algum limite é excedido.
- Opcionalmente, "mata" conexões excessivas.

Normalmente o plugin possui um link para donwload dentro do próprio WHM, na seção de plugins.

Comment: Muito obrigado Daniel. 
Havia verificado algo sobre isso, mas pelo que vi ele não está compatível com meu WHM.

Comment: Você pode atualizar, em plugins: `QuickInstall WHM Admin`

Comment: O local varia com a versão e até mesmo o theme que usa no WHM. Tabmém pode baixar diretamente do site do desenvolvedor e instalar manualmente.

Comment: Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2):

eu sei que isto possivelmente não responde à sua pergunta, mas considere um paradigm de nosql para bases de dados, como por exemplo postgre, ou nosql. em alternativa algo do género ruby on rails. ficou o conselho

Comment: Já trabalho em algumas aplicações Nosql, mas não tenho como migrar agora aplicações antigas para o Nosql.